# APNS - notifications push ios: Connection reset by peer PHP

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I have had Push Notifications working fine. But some of the times, from nowhere it starts giving error:

***stream_socket_client(): SSL: Connection reset by peer***

> Weird thing is i don't have to do anything to resolve it but wait.
>   After sometime, it starts working back again.

I know it is a **duplicate** of many questions like:
[notifications-push-ios-connection-reset-by-peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706286/notifications-push-ios-connection-reset-by-peer)
But none of them solves my problem.

I am using PHP stream_socket_client to generate the socket connection

Code in use is:

```
 <?php
ini_set('display_errors','On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$deviceToken= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';      
$passphrase = ' ';
$message = 'my first notification';
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
// Close the connection
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really put my finger on main reason for it.

***But please make sure, you are not doing any of the below things wrong:***

- **Don't make many connections in parallel**. Either reuse the same connection or close the connection after delivering Push Notifications. Actually, servers have a limit for maximum number of parallel connections, which might leave you in trouble, once you reach threshold. Also Apple suggests leave a connection open unless you know it will be idle.

> Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications;
>   don’t repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid
>   connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack. You should
>   leave a connection open unless you know it will be idle for an
>   extended period of time—for example, if you only send notifications to
>   your users once a day it is ok to use a new connection each day.

- **Don't send out developer profile tokens to LIVE APNS.** Keep distribution and development app tokens separate. It could result in error, if you try to send sandbox tokens to LIVE APNS or vice versa.

Comment: I think, i might not be closing the connection correctly. I will verify it.

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with this one for a while. For my case it turned out to be either:

a) and expired APNS certificate. Only a very small percentage of the errors explained that it was an expired cert. Most were "connection reset by peer".

b) a corrupt APNS certificate. Only after regenerating the certificate did it start working. Until that point, I was again getting the infamous "connection reset by peer".