# How many connections `FCM` & `APN` allows in parallel

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apn

I have to know something. I want to know How many connections `FCM` & `APN` allows  in parallel. I google it and find the `FCM` allows `1000` connections in parallel but did not know How many connections `APN` allows in parallel. I also want that is there any other way to increase the connections in  `FCM` & `APN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t's better not to make any connections in parallel, it is recommended to reuse connections or close the connections after delivering Push notifications.

> Also Apple suggests leave a connection open unless you know it will be
>   idle. It appears a rule of thumb is **15 connections max**.

Therefore, it's better not to increase the connections in APN. [Connections via FCM](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/e5260e) has only limit of 1000 notifications at one go.

Also, check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029235/apns-notifications-push-ios-connection-reset-by-peer-php) for more info.